# Optional AutoIncrement with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Transaction table that contains a TranRefId (for grouping purchase & reversal transactions together).  The interface with the SQL database is using Entity Framework 4.  I would like to be able to do 2 things...

1. Explicitly specify a value for the TranRefId
2. Auto-generate a value (whether by querying the MAX and incrementing or by some other means) when none is specified.

My concern, as this is a web application, is that there could will be multiple threads performing this action simultaneously.  If I do Select Max(TranRefId) and increment the value, there is a strong chance that multiple transactions will end up with the same value (due to concurrency).  **Is there any solution within the Entity Framework to help with concurrency issues like this??**

Also, TranRefId is only specific to the account.  See sample data below...

**Transaction Table**  (My apologies, don't know how else to make a table on here...)

TranId_**_***TranRefId***_**_Account

1_***_*__*_*____***1****_*__*_*__*_*_***A

2****_*__*_*__*_*__***1****_*__*_*__*_*_***A

3****_*__*_*__*_*__***1****_*__*_*____***B

4****_*__*_*__*_*__***2****_*__*_*____***B

5****_*__*_*__*_*__***1****_*__*_*__*_***_C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to have TranRefId column as an int you could make it a uniqueidentifier.  Then you could generate a new Guid and set the value to that - knowing that it would always be unique.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I do need to be able to manually insert TranRefIds that come from outside our system.

Comment: So changing TranRefId to a string instead and setting it's value to a new Guid (converted to a string) for internal ref numbers and to the actual external ref values (convert int to string) would be out of the question?

Comment: Hmmm...I'll have to think that one over.  My only hesitation is that we print the TranRefIds on receipts for customers to reference, which could be a bit lengthy.  Not to mention we do a large number of queries against the DB on this field, so keeping it as an INT would be preferred to keep performance up.

Comment: Figured I should come back and update this one.  Ended up going with a variation on this one...converted the TranRefID field to a bigint and using the current ticks.  The chance that a collision will happen with this method is low enough for our purposes and its a pretty fast way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could add another auto-column on the table and in a trigger (yech!) check to see if the value is set and if not move the auto-column value over.

Comment: Interesting thought.  Triggers are pretty inexpensive, no?  Definitely seems faster than doing it in user space.  The only remaining concern I would have would be avoiding duplicate entries.  However, I suppose this could be avoided by switching to bigint, capping manual entries at a certain value, and setting the autoincrement seed to just beyond the cap.